# Reverse a usb configured as a CD ROM?

Tags: usb

I have a usb drive that is read by the computer as a CDFS [Proporties window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnNxN.png) of the usb drive, and I want to have it as a usb storage device.

I tried diskpart in cmd.exe, and then tried to clean it there, but I've got the following error: virtual disk service error:there is no media in the device

Comment: @User552853 looks similar to my problem, but doesn't give a solution, if it is not possible to do it through config (or other software measures) there must be a way on the hardware side. (when I find a solution I'll post an answer)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try device manager, find your usb (or possibly listed as cd rom drive), in properties, delete drive, then refresh to see if it comes back as a usb and not a cd rom.  I know this is basic, but it's worth trying.

Comment: I found it listed in Disk drives, in DVD/CD-ROM drives and in usb controllers, I've tried removing them, but when I refresh it comes back as it was before

Answer (score 0):

I find the SD Association's official [SD Card Formatter tool](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/) (freeware) is very good for fixing removable drives that report the wrong capacity, type, etc. Give that a shot.

Comment: doesn't detect it

Comment: Dang, thought that would do it. Sorry for getting your hopes up.

Comment: :) no problem, that could have worked, so thanks for the suggestion